# Oman visa for a young Morrocan woman

Tags: visas, female-travellers, oman

As I hear a lot of talks about Oman goverment not giving visa for young morrocan travellers. Does it still exists? Is there any possibilities of getting a tourist or visit visa for a girl from morroco aged about 26?

Comment: Officially there is nothing regarding this. Practically, yes it happens, they do refuse visas for young girls from certain countries travelling alone, I recall Russia and its neighbors and Morocco.

Answer (score 4):

If you are traveling alone, then it is highly likely that you will be refused a visa; as you are of a high risk demographic - **especially if you are unmarried**.

This is mainly to stop exploitation of women.

It is not just Oman, I have seen it done in Saudi Arabia (but not for girls, but for single men traveling from Nepal - the officer suspected underage labor and refused entry) and in Bahrain (for risk of exploitation).

The only exception that I know of is if you are traveling as part of a tour group or educational trip.

Answer (score 1):

You have heard that the Oman government is reluctant to issue visas to young travellers, and in your own case a 26 year-old female from Morocco.

This rumour may be well founded, but it is certainly not the case for Oman alone!

Single women, especially of marriageable age, have unique problems with visas all over the world. Of course it exists, but is measured as a RISK factor rather than a sexist one.

The RISK factors include

- Probability that the applicant will get married and overstay
- Probability that the applicant will engage in illegal activities such
  as prostitution and drug dealing
- Probability that the applicant is being victimized by trafficking or
  blackmail
- Probability that the applicant will become dependent upon the state
  for welfare

Countries use their own performance histories to establish risk, and their performance histories are built up over time based upon applicant demographics: nationality, age, status, and so on.

If you fit one of their high-risk profiles, you have to try much harder to get a visa.  This holds true in virtually all countries.